# get multiple elements by class name

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, element

i'm trying to return an array of elements in `UIWebView` using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

HTML structure:

```
<tbody>
<tr data-item-id="">
<td class="item">
<img src="">
<a href="">Item</a>
</td>
<td>
<img src="">
</td>
<td class="price">price</td>
<td class="positive">change</td>
</tr>
```

my code currently looks like this.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('item');\
               for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {\
               links[i].innerHTML;}
```

I don't know if I'm doing it right, seeing as I don't know much javascript. This isn't outputting an array of all the elements with that class name, it only returns the last element with that classname.

Any help figuring this issue out is a big help, thank you.

Comment: no one as an answer for me? or at least a point in the right direction? I'm trying to make an array of elements, and then load a tableview with the elements